# How does tree know whether to build a classification or regression tree?

Tags: r

I am learning to classification/regression build trees and would like to understand how the tree function knows whether to build a classification or regression tree.

The following build a classification tree:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)

Carseats <- Carseats %>% mutate(High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")))
tree.carseats <- tree(High~ . -Sales, Carseats)
```

While this creates a regression tree:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(1)
tree.boston=tree(medv~ .,Boston)
```

To me both calls to tree look the same. Does it determine this based in the type of the target that is to be predicted?

Comment: https://wiki.c2.com/?UseTheSourceLuke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I aggree with duckmayr, I found nearly hidden in the documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf 
that in the `tree` function the `formula` argument is described as :

`"A formula expression. The left-hand-side (response) should be either a numerical vector when a regression tree will be fitted or a factor, when a classification
tree is produced."`

**Thus** your assumption was right, if the target is a factor then a classification tree is fitted and a regression tree is fitted otherwise.